# Maximum value of 1 bit hexadecimal

Tags: hex, verilog

`1'hF` or `1'h1`?
I am guessing 1'hF is not correct, 4'hF is required because 1 bit is not enough to hold a hexadecimal?

Comment: `1'hF` will be truncated to `1'h1`.

Answer (score 0):

in the 1'h1,1'h or 1'b or 1'd All said number of bits,as well as "4'h"show four  binary system,so hexadecimal "f" convert binary is "1111" ,so we need use "4'hf" show this

Answer (score 0):

The LRM section *5.7.1 Integer literal constants* say this about any *based literal constant*

> If the size of the unsigned number is larger than the size specified
> for the literal constant, the unsigned number shall be truncated from
> the left

Most tools also generate a warning if it has to truncate.